# Index goes out of range in for-loop requirements

Tags: c#, for-loop

I declared a string inside main method and let user to enter it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string phrase;
    Console.Write("Type english letters.\nEnter phrase");
    phrase = Console.ReadLine();
    morseCode(phrase);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Outside main, I declared a void function. This function suppose to send every element of the string to another function which returns the morse translation of the alphabet but I do not have problem with that function.

Here is the void function

```
static void morseCode(string p)
{
    for(int i=0; p[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(morseEncode(p[i]) + "/");
    }
}
```

I use VS. I get no errors from debugger and I can execute the code. It does what it suppose to. But while its running I get this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Error indictator points to for-loop. I did something wrong inside requirements. As I said, code works but I want to fix this problem.

Comment: didnt you just post exactly this question about 1 hour ago

Comment: @pm100 I provided you with lack of information so I deleted that an hour ago

Comment: The second part of your for loop `p[i] != '\0';` is not correctly evaluating how many times to iterate the for loop. Your loop tries to run more times than `p` has characters so `i` is out of range. Correctly determining how many times to loop will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c# strings are not 0 terminated you must do

```
static void morseCode(string p)
{
    for(int i=0; i<p.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(morseEncode(p[i]) + "/");
    }
}
```

Comment: you should make sure you understand exactly why you were getting the original error and why thins fixed it

Comment: I got used to code in C and things work just like that in there for strings. I thought it was same with c#

Answer (score 0):

since you dont need the index you can just do

```
foreach(char c in p)
    Console.Write(morseEncode(c) + "/");
```